# Joining an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, arrayref

I have an array `@ary` of unknown size. Each element, `$ary[$i]`, is an arrayref of unknown size. Each element of *that*, `$ary[$i][$j]`, is a string.

I wish to concatenate all of the `$ary[0][$j]` with all of the `$ary[1][$j]` with all of the… and so on.

That is, suppose my array looks like this:

```
$ary[0] = ['foo', 'fun'];
$ary[1] = ['bar', 'bun', 'blip'];
$ary[2] = ['baz', 'zun'];
```

Then I'd want the `return` to be:

```
(
'foo bar baz',
'foo bar zun',
'foo bun baz',
'foo bun zun',
'foo blip baz',
'foo blip zun',
'fun bar baz',
'fun bar zun',
'fun bun baz',
'fun bun zun',
'fun blip baz',
'fun blip zun'
)
```

(Alternatively, the `return` could be an array of arrayrefs: `(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['foo', 'bar', 'zun'], …)`.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest starting with an array of indexes, and then iterate through all combinations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @array = (
    [qw(foo fun)],
    [qw(bar bun blip)],
    [qw(baz zun)],
);

my @index = (0) x @array;

SET:
while (1) {
    my @set = map { $array[$_][ $index[$_] ] } (0 .. $#index);

    say "@set";

    $index[-1]++;

    for my $i (reverse 0 .. $#index) {
        if ($index[$i] > $#{ $array[$i] }) {
            $index[$i] = 0;
            if ($i > 0) {
                $index[$i - 1]++;
            } else {
                last SET;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
foo bar baz
foo bar zun
foo bun baz
foo bun zun
foo blip baz
foo blip zun
fun bar baz
fun bar zun
fun bun baz
fun bun zun
fun blip baz
fun blip zun
```

There are cpan modules to do this type of combination, but don't know them off hand.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arry= ();
$arry[0] = ['foo', 'fun'];
$arry[1] = ['bar', 'bun', 'blip'];
$arry[2] = ['baz', 'zun'];

my @combos = ();
$combos[0] = [''];

for my $i (1 .. @arry) {
  for my $j (0 .. @{$combos[$i - 1]} - 1) {
    push @{$combos[$i]}, "$combos[$i - 1][$j] $_" for @{$arry[$i - 1]};
  }
}
my @goodcombos = @{$combos[-1]};
s/^ // for @goodcombos;
print "$_\n" for @goodcombos;
```

It builds up the required concatenations, storing the first terms in `$combos[1]`, the concatenations of the first 2 terms in `$combos[2]`, the concatenations of the first 3 terms in `$combos[3]`, and so on.

Comment: (But I suspect [Miller's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31660825) is better than mine for large arrays. His uses two loops, whereas mine uses three. And mine loads a lot of stuff into memory that his doesn't.)